# Left join behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have a small query below. #t1 and #t2 are 2 little tables. I am trying to do a simple left join for both these tables and I see the output.

query:

```
    create table #t1 (cid int, program varchar(20), PP varchar(20), Startdate date, enddate date,codeset varchar(20),visitID int)
insert into #t1
values
(1001,'P1','ORD','2018-09-27','2018-09-28','OL',150),
(1001,'P2','ORD','2018-09-29',NULL,'IR',151)

create table #t2 (cid int,visitID int, answer varchar(20))
insert into #t2 
values
(1001,150,'Credited')

select t1.cid, t1.Startdate, t1.Enddate,t2.answer
from #t1 t1
left join #t2 t2 on  t1.cid = t2.cid 

drop table #t1, #t2
```

The output is:

[image]

To the logic of left join, all the records from left table and only matching records from the right table should show up. Why do I see 'Credited' in the second row when no such record exist in #t1?

desired output:

[image]

I'm missing something silly and unable to figure out. Any help?!

Comment: It's joining on CID, which is in both rows, so Credited shows up on both rows

Comment: You join on `cid` and for both rows from `#t1` the `cid` is `1001` and a row with `cid` `1001` also exists in `#t2`. So it gets joined to both rows. That's how a left join works.

Comment: `t2` needs additional columns to indicate whether it joins to first row or the second in `t1`. Without this criteria it will join to both.

Comment: What does EndDate tell you? It means nothing to me. Does that have significance on whether or not it should say Credited? If so, you need to include this as part of the join condition

Comment: Edited the question. Added additional columns that I missed to add before

Comment: @Rick It's not clear to me WHY the first row should say credited and the second row not. You've not specified that yet. Without providing that info, this question will likely get closed

Comment: The join is behaving correctly.  On the other hand, something is wrong with your logic.

Comment: Hi. "all the records from left table and only matching records from the right table should show up" is not clear. But the Credited row *does* "match"--ON t1.cid = t2.cid. Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. See [mcve]--that includes a clear specification. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the expected behavior. You are joining on CID. The single record in #t2 has a CID value of 1001. That matches both records in #t1 since both records in #t1 have value of 1001; thus, you have two rows in your results with a value of Credited for the column answer.

Comment: Agree. 1001 for the Start date 9/29 has no record in #t2 so why is it showing 'Credited' thr? How can I get the answer for the second record as NULL?

Comment: Are there additional columns that you are not telling us about? For the second row in #t1, shoud the value of CID be something different? With the details we have up to this point, an inner join and left join will give the same results with this dataset.

Comment: There are additional columns. Will update the question

Answer (score 1):

You apparently want to join `cid` **and** `visitid`.

```
SELECT t1.cid,
       t1.startdate,
       t1.enddate,
       t2.answer
       FROM #t1 t1
            LEFT JOIN #t2 t2
                      ON t1.cid = t2.cid
                         AND t1.visitid = t2.visitid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get such output with data and join condition you have. You are joining #t1 to #t2 by cid and you have the same cid for both records in #t2 table thats mean that one record from the #t2 with cid 1001 will be joined to both of records in table #t2.

You can get such output if you will change id of second line in #t1 to 1002 but I don't know is it correct for your task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only show Credited where there is an EndDate specified, you need to add to your join condition.

```
select t1.cid, t1.Startdate, t1.Enddate,t2.answer
from #t1 t1
left join #t2 t2 on  t1.cid = t2.cid AND t1.EndDate IS NOT NULL
```

If it's the visitID and not the EndDate that causes this, then use this query:

```
select t1.cid, t1.Startdate, t1.Enddate,t2.answer
from #t1 t1
left join #t2 t2 on  t1.cid = t2.cid AND t1.visitId = 150
```

We don't have enough info right now to really know what your logic requires but it will likely look something like the above.

Comment: Please don't answer unclear questions, it makes a mess. Post a comment asking for clarifying edits.

Comment: Philip the root of the question is clear but the details which aren't that important here are still missing